# Convert delimited string to object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a delimited key/value string into an object in javascript and finding my javascript-fu lacking.

I have something like:

```
"rating:1,2,3"
```

and I'd like to turn it into something like

```
{rating: [1,2,3]}
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this

Comment: If the string is in JSON format, you can use `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "rating:1,2,3";
var splitStr = str.split(":");

var obj = {};
obj[splitStr[0]] = splitStr[1].split(",").map(function(value) {return parseInt(value, 10)});
```

Comment: Note that this will give `{rating:["1","2","3"]}` rather than `{rating:[1,2,3]}`.

Comment: This is way more elegant then what i ended up coming up with. Thanks.